# jQuery Form image upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have recently tried using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload for file upload, but I'm not entirely sure how to upload the image to a certain folder on the server.

Heres the jQuery:

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();
```

and then the HTML:

```
<h1>File Upload Progress Demo #3</h1>
<code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile[]"></code><br>
<code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile[]"></code><br>
<code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile[]"></code>
<form action="files-raw.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side code is responsible for save the uploaded files to the server, As you are using PHP you can access the file through `$_FILES["myfile"]`. I assume you want code like this,

```
$newdirectory = "/your/directory";
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $filename)
{
    $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count];
    move_uploaded_file($temp, $newdirectory . '/' . basename($filename));
    $count++;
}
```

This should do as you are asking. More info on handling uploads [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and on `move_uploaded_file` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: It seems to work for the most part.. but it still doesn't seem to be putting the image in the directory..

Comment: Maybe try `print_r($_FILES);` to make sure the files are recieved by the server.

Comment: first thing i did, and i may be wrong but the response seemed quiet good response: Array ( [myfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpZt2TEZ ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 879394 ) ) )

Comment: Yep seems healthy, maybe update your question with the full upload script so I can see the context.

Comment: well other then what you posted that is the full script so far.. also it works in Firefox but not IE, yet both return the same responses

Answer (score 0):

if it is in MVC then in view

```
<form action="Home/HandleFileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>
```

and in Controller write this...

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult HandleFileUpload()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-File-Name"]))
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Uploads/{0}", Request.Headers["X-File-Name"]));
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                return this.Json(new { success = true });
            }

            return this.Json(new { success = false });
        }
       }
```

Comment: its not mvc, no.. but it could be... I tried altering as you suggested.. but its not working out for me..

Comment: what technology are you using? PHP or .net?

Comment: PHP.. most likely why it didn't work.. (wow i feel stupid now)

Comment: go thorugh this link.. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and why u feeling stupid? every technology has its own demand!